# Issues while trying to clone repository from local server to git user machine

Tags: git

I am receiving  error while trying to clone repository.git folder from  a machine(which behaves as `server`)  to another machine(which behaves like `client`).The `Terminal commands` that I have tried and the response received are shown below.

```
sonya@sonya-desktop:~/workspace$ git clone sonya@192.168.1.153:/home/user153/remote_repository.git
Cloning into 'remote_repository'...
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.153 port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have tried with `SSH` also.The `Terminal commands` and the received response is given below.In both cases , I am facing same problem.

```
sonya@sonya-desktop:~/workspace$ git clone ssh://sonya@192.168.1.153/home/user153/remote_repository.git
Cloning into 'remote_repository'...
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.153 port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

Explanation of `Terminal commands`.

`sonya`:`Git username` I have created in my server machine.

`192.168.1.153`:`IP` of server machine

`/home/user153/remote_repository.git`:`Path` of the remote_repository.git(git folder) in the server machine.

Anyone please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can user `sonya` connect to the server `192.168.1.153` using `ssh` command?

Comment: Yes.I tried like this.The response is the same.               sonya@sonya-desktop:~/workspace$ git clone ssh://sonya@192.168.1.153/home/user153/remote_repository.git
Cloning into 'remote_repository'...
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.153 port 22: Connection refused
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Comment: No, I mean can you login on server using ssh: `ssh sonya@192.168.1.153`. If no try to get more info using debug `ssh -vvv sonya@192.168.1.153`

Comment: I tried what you said .The response is given below.I dont know why this happens since I am a newbie in linux.                           sonya@sonya-desktop:~/workspace$ ssh -vvv sonya@192.168.1.153
OpenSSH_5.9p1 Debian-5ubuntu1.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1 14 Mar 2012
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to 192.168.1.153 [192.168.1.153] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 192.168.1.153 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.153 port 22: Connection refused

Comment: Accessing repositories via SSH requires that an SSH daemon is installed and running on the machine. This doesn't seem to be the case -- the message simply means that no SSH server is responding at that IP address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `which sshd`.
If the command is not giving  any path to `sshd`.You have to install this.For installing `open ssh` in your server machine use `sudo apt-get install openssh-server`